# Traverse range forwards and backwards - Python

Tags: python-3.x, colors, range, stdout

I'm writing a script that will have some colorized text using colorama but I've ran into a snag. I need to use the ANSI escape codes for certain colors and I would like to have a gradient color.  So far I can produce the forward gradient by using a **for** statement:

`for i in range(22, 27):
     print(\e[35;5;i + "some text")`

However I can't figure out how to make the backwards gradient. I know in BASH script I can use the **for** statement like this:

`for i in {22..28} {27..21} ; do echo -en "\e[35;5;${i}m \e[0m" ; done ; echo`

Which will produce the result I'm looking for. Can I traverse a range in the same manner in Python? I've tried

`for i in range(22, 28) (28,21,-1)`

But that just gave an error. I'm still pretty new to Python so I'm not sure if my syntax is wrong or if I should try something different all together.

**Edit for Clarification**

The effect that I am trying to achieve will look similar to this:
[image: Gradient], but text and in a different color. I can make the dark-light gradient but cannot reverse it in the middle of the string to make the light-dark gradient.

**Update**

So I was able to achieve the effect I was looking for however it produces a gradient of all the colors, rather than **blue**. I used the **colr** library to achieve this:

`from colr import Colr as C
 print(c(' '.join(out)).gradient(name='blue'))`

which produces this output:

[image: bashwxplus image]

So I'm not sure if I even need the **for** statement or if I'm just not understanding how to produce these gradients for text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forgive me if I am misunderstanding your question but do you just mean reversing the order of range, like so:

```
for i in range(22,27): #forward
    print("\e[35;5;%dm \e[0m" % i)

for i in reversed(range(22,27)): #backward
    print("\e[35;5;%dm \e[0m" % i)
```

**EDIT**

If you wanted it to go from high number -> low -> high, all in one line, you could do:

```
my_range = list(reversed(range(22,27))) + list(range(22,27))
for i in my_range:
    print("\e[35;5;%dm \e[0m" % i)
```

Comment: Yes that will return the results that I'm looking for, but I need both **for** statements in one string, (I think). I edited the OP to add a picture of the effect I am trying to produce.

Comment: I think this makes sense now -- see my edits. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I am looking for! I had update the OP again to add a screenshot of what I am trying to do and what I have implemented to produce the gradient. I will plug your suggestion into my script and update.  Thanks for help!

Comment: no problem! If you are happy with it could you mark the check next to my answer plz!